# 'Use of app has been restricted'

Tags: authentication

When users are routed to my Facebook application without being logged in first, they receive the error "'Use of app has been restricted.' I have tried the different URL trick (as has been suggested before) but it doesn't seem to work. HTTP and HTTPS are enabled, Sandbox mode is off. The app is restricted to individuals in the United States and 18+ but I don't think an issue with that would produce the same error. If anyone can provide any assistance, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If user is not logged in, Facebook does not know whether the user is from US. One would expect this to work on IP addresses or something like that, but it does not.

I assume FB has some reasons for this. For example, if you're from USA and have an app working at home, you would expect it to keep working even if you travel to Canada and log in from there.